# .htacces (x2) to nginx rewrite - different rules in subdirectory (RazorCMS)

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

**Question is about translating RazorCMS (razorcms.co.uk) rewrite rule but I think answer can be general.**

I have two .htacces files. First is in main directory (/). I translated:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

to

```
location / { try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite; }
location @rewrite { rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1; }
```

There is no problem with this one.

Second .htacces file is in subdirectory (/rars).
Content inside is:

```
RewriteRule ^login/u/(.*)/p/(.*)$ index.php?login=1&u=$1&p=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^login index.php?login=1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L,QSA]
```

I tried to translate it to different rules:

```
location /login { rewrite ^/login/u/(.*)/p/(.*)$ /index.php?login=1&u=$1&p=$2 break; }
location /login { rewrite ^/login /index.php?login=1 break; }
location /rars { if (!-e $request_filename){ rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1; } }
```

...but it doesn't work.

**How can I translate .htaccess rules to Nginx rewrites if second .htaccess is in subdirectory? Can you point me in right direction?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx doesn't have per directory contexts, so you need to give the full path in the location. Try:

```
location /rars/login { rewrite ^/rars/login/u/(.*)/p/(.*)$ /rars/index.php?login=1&u=$1&p=$2 break; }
location /rars/login { rewrite ^/rars/login$ /rars/index.php?login=1 break; }
location /rars { if (!-e $request_filename){ rewrite ^/rars/(.*)$ /rars/index.php?path=$1; } }
```

Comment: Thank you. It was helpful.
I changed config to:
`location /login {
rewrite ^/login/u/(.*)/p/(.*)$ /rars/index.php?login=1&u=$1&p=$2 break;
rewrite ^/login$ /rars/index.php?login=1 break;
}
location /rars {  rewrite ^/rars/(.*)$ /rars/index.php?path=$1 last;}`
...and it seams to work but if I go to /login instead of execute /rars/index.php?login=1 nginx sends me "login" file with php code inside. Still looking for some mistake in config.